# Boundedness Theorem for continuous functions on intervals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Just want to confirm this is a suitable proof:

Assume $f$ is not bounded on $I$.  So, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lvert f(x)\rvert > n$.

Since $I$ is bounded, $x_n$ is also bounded.

By Bolzano-Weiestrauss Theorem, there exists $X' = (x_n)_r$ converging to $x$. Since I is bounded, so is $(x_n)_r$ and thus $x \in I$.

Since $f$ is continuous, the sequence $(f(x)) = f(x)$, so $(f(x))$ is bounded.

HOWEVER THIS IS A CONTRADICTION, as we said $\lvert f(x)\rvert > n >= r$.

Comment: Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ continuous on $(0,1)$.. Is it bounded??

Answer (score 0):

You need $I$ to be closed.

Your notation is a bit off at points

$\exists x_n$ such that $|f(x_n)|>n.$

The sequence $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_r}$ which converges to some point $x \in I.$ This uses that $I$ is closed and bounded.

We have by continuity that

$$f(x_{n_r}) \to f(x)$$
We also have $$|f(x_{n_r}| \to \infty.$$ These statements are not compatible 
since convergent sequences are bounded so we have a contradiction.

(Personally i prefer to proof this without contradiction and I give a more constructive proof in my book "Proof patterns")